# Issue with character entities in XML output

Tags: ruby, rspec

I am using "rest-client" to run a GET request and output XML is containing &lt and &gt characters instead of '<>'. I tried using to_xml method but it is not working. I am using NOKOGIRI to search a particular string in the output.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<string xmlns="http://host.xyz.com">&lt;NewDataSet&gt;
&lt;CUST_LAST_NM&gt;Lastname&lt;/CUST_LAST_NM&gt;
&lt;CUST_FRST_NM&gt;Firstname&lt;/CUST_FRST_NM&gt;
&lt;CUST_SHRT_NM&gt;short&lt;/CUST_SHRT_NM&gt;
```

Comment: Please provide more details. Can you provide a code sample, input and output?

Comment: rest-client natively uses UTF-8, which means the server that is sending the request could be at fault and is sending the date in wrong encoding. Try forcing encoding to UTF-8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Method 1**

Since you are using [Nokogiri](https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri), you could use

```
Nokogiri::HTML.parse "&lt;CUST_LAST_NM&gt;Lastname&lt;/CUST_LAST_NM&gt"
```

**Method 2** (If you are using Rails)

If you need this done in the views,

```
<%= raw '&lt;CUST_LAST_NM&gt;Lastname&lt;/CUST_LAST_NM&gt' %>
```

works too.

**Method 3**

You could also use the CGI library

```
CGI.unescapeHTML("&lt;CUST_LAST_NM&gt;Lastname&lt;/CUST_LAST_NM&gt")
```